# Создание базы данных SQLite в python

Tags: django

Хочу создать БД SQLite в своем приложении. Для этого в файле `models.py` пишу следующее:

```
class Article(models.Models):

    # Класс для дополнительных свойств таблицы (например, название таблицы)
    # Если не создать для этого класс, то такие свойства будут автоматически созданы Django
    class Meta:
        db_table = "article" # название таблицы

    # Поле заголовка
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length = 200) # CharField подразумевает набор символов, используется для небольших текстовых хранилищь информации

    # Поле статьи
    article_text  = models.TextFild() # TextFild - для больших массивов информации

    # После даты и времени статьи
    article_date  = models.DateTimeField() # DateTimeField - формат хранения и времени и даты

    # Поле хранения лайков
    article_likes = models.IntegerField()
```

При попытке выполнения команды `python manage.py migrate` выскакиевает следующая ошибка:

```
File "/home/sergei/djangoenv/bin/firstapp/article/models.py", line 8
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file
  /home/sergei/djangoenv/bin/firstapp/article/models.py
  on line 8, but no encoding declared;
  see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

В чем дело?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в кодировке, добавь в начале файла:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Первая строчка не обязательна, она задаёт как будет интерпретироваться файл shell'ом, но вы никогда не будете запускать файл models напрямую. Это актуально только для файла manage.py